# How to let a Tizen wearable Device communicate in two directions with UWP App vie Wi-Fi?

Tags: c#, wifi, tizen-web-app

Scenario:

- I have a Samsung Gear S3 Tizen web-app which is collecting data.
- I also have a UWP App written in C#, which reads the Data from the Gear and is also capable of sending information (short notes, update messages, etc.) to the gear app, which will then display this information.

Until now, the communication between these two runs over bluetooth with the Gear acting as the Server and UWP acting as a Client. But the circumstances in which they will be used, need a technology with expanded range in comparison to bt. I think of Wi-Fi here, but I am a total newbie to the coding of network communication. Where should I start? Which protocols and Server-Client construct is sensibly used in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Produce JSON from your UWP app (Server) and consume these JSON as rest client from your Tizen Web App(Client App) 
Imagine your UWP produce JSON data like http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all, then consume this as below example simply,

```
function getServerData() {
        'use strict';

        console.log( "ready!" );
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all",
            success: function (data) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                 // use data wherever you need it 
             }
       });
    }
```

And don't forget to add these privileges and accesses in order to make it work.

**config.xml**

```
    <access origin="http://groupkt.com" subdomains="true"></access>
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How does the communication in the other direction work? Same way? How does the Ajax request work in c#? Btw luckily I already implemented the data to be exchanged as JSON data

Comment: On the server side you need to implement a Rest Service which will produce JSON data

Comment: So, What is your result ?\

Comment: I have to admit that I did not use rest for this, but Json. The Json strings are sent over a simple tcp-websocket. This solution works, but it has problems with sending data frequently (i.e. every 100ms). At some point the uwp app stops receiving the messages.

Comment: Did you find any log?

Comment: What Do you mean by finding a log?

Comment: Well there is no error thrown, but when I write the received messages to the debug console, they seem to be decoded the wrong way. As if somewhere along the way one of the first few byte of each message gets lost